# OS Features missing after upgrade to Android 5.1

Tags: updates, stock-android, fastboot, 5.1-lollipop

I just updated my Nexus 5 from Android 5.0 LPX13D to 5.1 LMY47I. Some components of the OS now seem to be missing. When I scroll with two fingers from the top of the screen I only get the notifications pane, not the quick settings pane, and I don't seem to get notifications at all. My phone vibrates but nothing shows up in the notifications pane.

Since LPX13D was a developer preview, I didn't have an OTA update available, so I downloaded the factory image of LMY47I from Google's website and flashed it via `adb` and `fastboot`. I followed the instructions on [the nexus image page](https://developers.google.com/android/nexus/images), although I already had an unlocked bootloader, so I didn't have to do that step, and I also changed the last line of the `flash-all` script from

```
    fastboot -w update image-hammerhead-lmy47i.zip
```

to

```
    fastboot update image-hammerhead-lmy47i.zip
```

Which, according to a blog I found, tells fastboot not to perform a factory reset when it updates the OS from the image. However, I'm thinking this must caused LMY47I to not be installed correctly.

I've wiped the cache partition and re-flashed the OS from the image on google's website, which doesn't seem to have fixed the issue. Any ideas as to what I can do short of a full factory reset?

Comment: I flashed the same image, but I didn't have the dev preview installed, and it works absolutely fine for the issues you mentioned. I did, however, factory reset. You could flash the file again, but maybe in sections, don't wipe it all and try to keep the data. To be honest usually a clean flash is the best way to go, but it's a bit annoying.